# In Windows Version 10.0.18363 Cannot Switch to Windows container in Docker

Tags: docker, windows-10, windows-container

#### Context:

-Windows version: 10.0.18363 Build 18263 
-Docker Information:

```
 Cloud integration: 1.0.17
 Version:           20.10.8
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.16.6
 Git commit:        3967b7d
 Built:             Fri Jul 30 19:58:50 2021
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true
```

-Computer: Surface Laptop 3

-Docker Settings: 
[Docker Settings Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqlBI.png)

#### Problem:

In the past four days I have been unable to switch to windows containers on my computer and also unable to run windows containers. Every time I try to switch to windows containers I get the following error:

```
System.ServiceProcess.TimeoutException:
Time out has expired and the operation has not been completed.
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus desiredStatus, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Docker.Backend.Processes.WindowsDockerDaemon.TryToStartService(Settings settings, String args, Dictionary`2 env) in C:\workspaces\master-merge\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\Processes\WindowsDockerDaemon.cs:line 208
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass6_1.<GetExecutor>b__0(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
```

I then get the option to "Reset to factory defaults" which when I click it, it hangs for a long time while docker tries to start-up again and eventually crashes. I have tried: restarting my computer, restarting Docker, uninstalling and re-installing Docker, deleting the `daemon.json` file, and downgrading my version of windows and then upgrading it again. I do not know what to try from here to get my windows containers working on my machine.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There's no code, it was an issue when trying to run docker containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following this [link](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/11899) I just went under c:/ProgramData/Docker and removed the read-only permissions on the panic.log file. Then I restarted Docker and it worked.